# linux shell script: split string, put them in an array then loop through them

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string based on delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash)

In a bash script how do I split string with a separator like `;` and loop through the resulting array?

Comment: This sounds like homework. Regardless, what have you tried so far? Post something that shows you're trying.

Comment: not a homework question. just no familiar with shell script. 
i have been googling but found nothing quite what i am looking for.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can probably skip the step of explicitly creating an array...

One trick that I like to use is to set the inter-field separator (IFS) to the delimiter character. This is especially handy for iterating through the space or return delimited results from the stdout of any of a number of unix commands.

Below is an example using semicolons (as you had mentioned in your question):

```
export IFS=";"
sentence="one;two;three"
for word in $sentence; do
  echo "$word"
done
```

Note: in regular Bourne-shell scripting setting and exporting the IFS would occur on two separate lines (IFS='x'; export IFS;).

Comment: I think you should store IFS before modifying it, in an temp variable and restore it back once you are done with it!!

Comment: I'd recommend either doing this in a subshell (wrap in parentheses) or saving and restoring IFS (OLDIFS="$IFS" ...code... export IFS="$OLDIFS") - a lot of funky things can happen if it's not set right.

Comment: thanks. i am using this script and also saving and restoring ifs according to jefromi. but i get this error
export: =: bad variable name
did i do something wrong?

Comment: It is not necessary to export IFS. Just save it `oldIFS=$IFS`, set it `IFS=';'`, do stuff, and restore it `IFS=$oldIFS`.

Comment: You saved me, thank you

Comment: I would use exprt IFS="," instead because if the input is feed from argument then the argument containing ; could have a different meaning than just a separator

Answer (score 37):

If you don't wish to mess with IFS (perhaps for the code within the loop) this might help.

If know that your string will not have whitespace, you can substitute the '**;**' with a space and use the *for/in* construct:

```
#local str
for str in ${STR//;/ } ; do 
   echo "+ \"$str\""
done
```

But if you *might* have whitespace, then for this approach you will need to use a temp variable to hold the "rest" like this:

```
#local str rest
rest=$STR
while [ -n "$rest" ] ; do
   str=${rest%%;*}  # Everything up to the first ';'
   # Trim up to the first ';' -- and handle final case, too.
   [ "$rest" = "${rest/;/}" ] && rest= || rest=${rest#*;}
   echo "+ \"$str\""
done
```

Comment: Why the down-vote w/o a comment?   You should justify that....

Comment: I use the first method using using  `${STR//;/ }` syntax. But I got a problem now, that if I pass a string which doesn't have the delimiter, it gives an error: "Bad substitution". I'd like to treat such strings as an array with one element. Do you have any suggestion to get around this issue?

Answer (score 13):

Here's a variation on **ashirazi's** answer which doesn't rely on `$IFS`. It does have its own issues which I ouline below.

```
sentence="one;two;three"
sentence=${sentence//;/$'\n'}  # change the semicolons to white space
for word in $sentence
do
    echo "$word"
done
```

Here I've used a newline, but you could use a tab "`\t`" or a space. However, if any of those characters are in the text it will be split there, too. That's the advantage of `$IFS` - it can not only enable a separator, but disable the default ones. Just make sure you save its value before you change it - as others have suggested.

Comment: You could just do `for word in ${sentence//;/$'\n'}` (omit the second assignment). To loop only on newlines, you can do something like `echo ${sentence//;/$'\n'} | while read elem; do echo "$elem"; done`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example code that you may use:

```
$ STR="String;1;2;3"
$ for EACH in `echo "$STR" | grep -o -e "[^;]*"`; do
    echo "Found: \"$EACH\"";
done
```

grep -o -e "[^;]*" will select anything that is not ';', therefore spliting the string by ';'.

Hope that help.

Comment: thanks, but for some reason, it doesnt loop. it only outputs

Comment: @Funky Dude: It loops for me.

Comment: The '$' in front of STR and for means the shell prompt, You omit that. I am dead sure it work as I using it right now. :D

Comment: i did take it out and put it in a shell script

Comment: Ummm. That is strange. I really don't know why. Just in case, though, see what I did here: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1961549/images/It_works.jpg .

Comment: This only works, if your strings doesn't contain whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence="one;two;three"
a="${sentence};"
while [ -n "${a}" ]
do
    echo ${a%%;*}
    a=${a#*;}
done
```

Comment: An explanation would improve this answer