# Get exact output of a shell command

Tags: bash, shell

The `bash` manual says regarding [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.

Demonstration - 3 characters, newlines first:

```
$ output="$(printf "\n\nx")"; echo -n "$output" | wc -c
3
```

Here the newlines are not at the end, and do not get removed, so the count is 3.

Demonstration - 3 characters, newlines last:

```
$ output="$(printf "x\n\n")"; echo -n "$output" | wc -c
1
```

Here the newlines are removed from the end, so the count is 1.

### TL;DR

What is a **robust** work-around to get the binary-clean output of a command into a variable?

Bonus points for Bourne shell compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it in a "Bourne compatible" way is to use external utilities.

Beside writting one in c, you can use `xxd` and `expr` (for example):

```
$ output="$(printf "x\n\n"; printf "X")"         # get the output ending in "X".
$ printf '%s' "${output}" | xxd -p               # transform the string to hex.
780a0a58
$ hexstr="$(printf '%s' "${output}" | xxd -p)"   # capture the hex
$ expr "$hexstr" : '\(.*\)..'                    # remove the last two hex ("X").
780a0a
$ hexstr="$(expr "$hexstr" : '\(.*\)..')         # capture the shorter str.
$ printf "$hexstr" | xxd -p -r | wc -c           # convert back to binary.
3
```

Shortened:

```
$ output="$(printf "x\n\n"; printf "X")"
$ hexstr="$(printf '%s' "${output}" | xxd -p )"
$ expr "$hexstr" : '\(.*\)..' | xxd -p -r | wc -c
3
```

The command `xxd` is being used for its ability to convert back to binary.

Note that wc will fail with many UNICODE characters (multibyte chars):

```
$ printf "Voilà" | wc -c
6

$ printf "★" | wc -c
3
```

It will print the count of bytes, not characters.

The length of a variable `${#var}` will also fail in older shells.

Of course, to get this to run in a Bourne shell you must use `` `…` `` instead of `$(…)`.

Comment: Thanks - I also learned about the use of `:` in `expr` to print only anchored patterns.

Comment: "Note that wc will fail with many UNICODE characters" "It will print the count of bytes, not characters." That's because you told it to count bytes, not characters. See `-m`: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, the `${parameter%word}` form of [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) can be used:

> ```
> $ output="$(printf "x\n\n"; echo X)"; echo -n "${output%X}" | wc -c
> 3
> ```

This is substitution is also specified by [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Comment: If someone runs Plan 9, could they try this in Bourne shell?

Comment: Nope, Bourne shell doesn't have `${var#str}`.

Comment: Chapter and verse? I'd love to find a "standards document" for it.

Comment: There is no standard for an specific implementation of a shell. In fact there are several implementations that are [all called bourne shells](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/). An spec is POSIX, and yes, it defines the `${var#str}` parameter substitution. I can point you to [one known implementation of the bourne shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html) manual. Conclusion: `${var#str}` is POSIX but not Bourne.